# Logged-In User is logged out after refresh (React + Firebase v9)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I was setting up a dashboard project with this tutorial : https://css-tricks.com/user-registration-authentication-firebase-react/

Everything is fine except when I'm reloading a page : I'm always back to the login page (because I'm disconnected)

I think it's an issue in this chunk of code in App.js :

```
function App() {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState({})
  const [timeActive, setTimeActive] = useState(false)
  
useEffect(()  => {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      setCurrentUser(user)
     })
  }, [])
  
  return (
    <Router>
       <AuthProvider value={{currentUser, timeActive, setTimeActive}}>
      <Switch>
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Profile} />
        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
        <Route exact path='/verify-email' component={VerifyEmail} />
      </Switch>
      </AuthProvider>
  </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I did some console.log inside useEffect and the output shows the state "currentUser" is empty for a moment, which I think is the reason a refresh disconnects me.

Do anyone knows a fix for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase APIs load auth state asynchronously so it can take a moment for it to load. You should use `onAuthStateChanged()` whenever your website loads and if the user is not logged then redirect to login and vice versa. For exameple:

```
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User present
    setCurrentUser(user)
    // redirect to home if user is on /login page 
  } else {
    // User not logged in
    // redirect to login if on a protected page 
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working! I just suspect there could be an infinite loop somewhere, I'll try to figure it out.